# how to move files from one ftp to another

Tags: c#, ftp

I need to move files from one ftp to another (currently using ftpwebrequest) both requiring authentication and have different settings (timeout, ascii, active etc).  Is downloading files from one to a local server and then uploading to the other significant slower than just copying the files (if that exists even, how would you do it, renameto?).  It feels like it should be faster but I'm not sure, I have no understanding of file copying or downloading.

they are all .txt or .csv and mostly around 3-10 mb each so quite a bit of data

Comment: Download from Server A to the machine running your app.  Then Upload to Server B...

Comment: Kind of depends on the size of the pipe between your servers. How many files are you dealing with and how big are they?

Answer (score 0):

You can copy a file from FTP-Server A to FTP-Server B using [FXP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_eXchange_Protocol). Both servers and the client have to support that feature.

Comment: they are very big and there are probably around 50 to 100 files or so.  I've been doing a bit of searching and it seems regardless of what they call it, it's some sort of download and then upload

Answer (score 0):

Some time we need to download, upload file from FTP server. Here is some good example for FTP operation in C#. 
You can use this. It will help you to make a C# program to full fill your requirements.

File Download from FTP Server

```
public void DownloadFile(stringHostURL, string UserName, string Password, stringSourceDirectory, string FileName, string LocalDirectory)
        {
            if(!File.Exists(LocalDirectory + FileName))
            {
                try
                {
                    FtpWebRequestrequestFileDownload = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(HostURL + “/” + SourceDirectory + “/” + FileName);
                    requestFileDownload.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UserName, Password);
                    requestFileDownload.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
                    FtpWebResponseresponseFileDownload = (FtpWebResponse)requestFileDownload.GetResponse();
                    StreamresponseStream = responseFileDownload.GetResponseStream();
                    FileStreamwriteStream = new FileStream(LocalDirectory + FileName, FileMode.Create);
                    intLength = 2048;
                    Byte[] buffer = new Byte[Length];
                    intbytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);
                    while(bytesRead > 0)
                    {
                        writeStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);
                    }
                    responseStream.Close();
                    writeStream.Close();
                    requestFileDownload = null;
                    responseFileDownload = null;
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    throwex;
                }
            }
        }
```

[Some Good Examples](http://cybarlab.com/download-upload-files-from-ftp-server-in-c-sharp)

Hope it will help you.